# how to restore window partition in ubuntu dual booting?

Tags: partitioning, window, restore

my pc hard disk 500gb.my computer C,D,E,F,G ,H Partition .c  is window 8 partition.H installed Ubuntu  12.10 used dual booting. I try replaced Ubuntu 13.04 install .I choose erase button few seconds I stopped installing.now window partition missed in  allocated 426.20 GB.how restore window partition without lose data. other 20 GB where I do know.any body help me thanks.